# Can't understand why I'm getting a segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm using very little memory on the stack, and I have no recursion, and all my memory access is on the stack. So why am I getting a segfault?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *file = fopen("test.cpp", "r");
  struct item{
    char *type;
    int price;
    bool wanted;
  };
  item items[100]; char *temp;
 if (file)
   cout << "works up to here" << endl;
  fscanf(file,
     "%s, %[for sale wanted], %d",
     items[0].type,
     temp,
     &items[0].price);
}
```

It prints out

```
works up to here
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your pointers aren't pointing to anything (valid). Also, other than `namespace std` and `cout` this is C. Use `std::ifstream` and `std::string` instead of `FILE` and `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf()` functions won't allocate any memory. From the looks of it you are passing uninitialized pointer to `fscanf()` where the function expects arrays of sufficient size instead.

Most likely you'd use something like

```
items[0].type = new char[100];
char temp[20];
if (3 == fscanf("%100s, %[for sale wanted], %d",
              items[0].type,
              temp,
              &items[0].price)) {
    // deal with a read item
}
else {
    // deal with an input error
}
```

(I'm not sufficiently familiar with `fscanf()` to be confident about the middle format specifier).

Comment: Why do I have to use `new`?

Comment: You can also use `malloc()` but it is harder to use than `new` in C++ (e.g., because C++ requires the result to be cast to the correct type). Alternatively you can change your `struct` to not contain a pointer to `char` but rather an array of `char` like `char type[100];` (the size should meet your needs, of course). Using an array in your `struct has the advantage that you don't need to release the memory.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing pointers to `fscanf` that are not initialized. You need to do something like this:
(if you are using C)

```
FILE* file = fopen(...);
char* str = malloc(N);
fscanf(file, "%s", str);
printf("Read %s\n", str);
free(str);
fclose(file);
```

(if you are actually using C++)

```
std::ifstream file(...);
std::string str;
file >> str;
std::cout << "Read " << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the `file` pointer is not null?

This is from [fopen reference doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> If the file is successfully opened, the function returns a pointer to
> a FILE object that can be used to identify the stream on future
> operations.
>
> Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.

And as Kevin mentioned, this is more like C than C++

Comment: Kevin's answer is correct, you are passing uninitialized char* to fscanf. BTW, that's not the way these things get done in C++ ;)

Comment: BTW, @RenéG, your `if (file)` does not work as you expect it. the fscanf still get called if the file is null. you'd need to put curly brackets around those two instructions. you know!

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of problems.

1. You are not checking whether `fopen()` was successful.
2. You are trying to read into `items[0].type`, which has not been initialized to point to anything valid.

You will be better off using `std::ifstream` and `std::string` instead of using `FILE*` and `char*`.